# 'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

how can i get client ip address in javascript or angular or ionic or codova??
i search a lot can't find the right solution?? how it is possible i also try this 
https://github.com/salbahra/NetworkInterfacePlugin/

but when i try to run this command

```
'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i am using ionic and cordova. (cordova plugins running fine)

Comment: phonegap is wrapper on cordova. You are saying that you are using ionic + cordova. To run phonegap plugin you need to install phonegap and set environment path. Or if you do not want to install phonegap, fire all command with cordova instead of phonegap.. This should work :)

Comment: means cordova plugin installed != phonegap installed ???

Comment: cordova plugin is same as phonegap plugin. But cordova is base for phonegap. So cordova is not same as phonegap. Phonegap is simple wrapper on cordova to make developer's life easy. But command line for both cordova and phonegap is different. So by installing cordova, you will not have phonegap installed.

Comment: good to see .. i need to install phonegap then i can run plugin..yeah?

Comment: yes.. or just run all command line with cordova instead of phonegap..

Comment: i run with cordova and it is installed thank you. now gonna add in config.xml ...

Comment: try this..  cordova local plugin add https://github.com/salbahra/NetworkInterfacePlugin